# Swift Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to load a table view which has been designed using the user interface builder(storyboard). I am trying to load the table view with the contents of an array. It is not necessary that the array always consist of some elements. The problem is that when I try to load it, it doesn't stop loading . I mean the the loading of tableview is in an infinite loop or something like that. I will show the code below. I am new to the swift language . Thanks in advance for the help.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("The Count Of PlayeArray is",self.playersArray.count)
    return self.playersArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   print("In Table View .....Table View Count", playersArray.count)
    var usrName : String!
    var usrRace : String!
    var imgName : String!

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",forIndexPath: indexPath ) as! TBLPlayerCellVC


    let player = playersArray[indexPath.row]

    print("------------------------------------------Number Of Connected Players--------------------------")
    print( playersArray.count)

    usrName = playersArray[indexPath.row].name
    if playersArray[indexPath.row].race.name == "xyz" {
        imgName = "db.png"
    }
    else if playersArray[indexPath.row].race.name == "hhh" {
        imgName = "so.png"
    }
    else if playersArray[indexPath.row].race.name == "ffff" {
        imgName = "rebels.png"
    }
    else {
        imgName = "uaa.png"
    }


    cell.lblUserName.text = usrName
    if(player.isInvited == false){
        cell.lblSelector.text = "❌"
    }
    else if (playersArray[indexPath.row].isInvited == true){
        cell.lblSelector.text = "✅"
    }

    cell.usrImage.image = UIImage(named:imgName)

    return cell
}

//specify the height of each row in the table view

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

Comment: If there is no item in the array then the output is,    The Count Of PlayeArray is 0
The Count Of PlayeArray is 0
The Count Of PlayeArray is 0
The Count Of PlayeArray is 0  ...This means the numberOfRowsInSection is called 4 times        ....If there is something in the array then table view doesn't stop loading.... the execution goes on continuously...

Comment: Maybe you call `tableView.reloadData()` somewhere.

Comment: You didn't post numberOfSections method

Comment: is it really required to use numberOfSections to load data......@AndriyGordiychuk